# ArgumentNullException in Newtonsoft.Json CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize a complex object from JSON for a contact but I am receiving `ArgumentNullException`

The error stack trace is:

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: method]
   System.Delegate.DelegateConstruct(Object target, IntPtr slot) +0
   Void .ctor(System.Object, IntPtr)(Object[] ) +132
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters(JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, ObjectConstructor`1 creator, String id) +1917
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +787
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +188
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IList list, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id) +1522
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id) +434
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +245
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) +404
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) +2540
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +839
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +188
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) +780
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +341
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +263
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +57
   ActiveCampaign.Net.Services.ContactService.GetContact(Int32 id) +139
   ArtsHub.active_campaign.btnGetContact_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +167
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +155
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3804
```

I did try changing some properties from DateTime? to string or object but it did not help.

The error is deep down in `Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObjectUsingCreatorWithParameters` and seems to beyond my knowledge.

The link to solution is https://dotnetfiddle.net/uIgRXS

I would appreciate help in this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within your `Contact` class you have a property `List<Action> Actions` but you don't have a matching class in your code - which means the compiler is using the class `System.Runtime.Action` class and cannot deserialize the JSON into that class.

Solution:

Add an Action class to your file

```
public class Action
{
    [JsonProperty("tstamp")]
    public DateTimeOffset Tstamp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

NOTE:

How did I find the answer? I removed different sections of the JSON and ran the code until I found the error. When I found out which section of the JSON was causing the problem I checked the object where that was defined and looked for the matching class. When I didn't find a class defined for that object in your code, I added it.

You should try and minimise the problem to as small a code as possible i.e. remove sections of you JSON. This will remove the parts that do work and isolate the exact code/JSON that is failing.

Hope that helps :-)

Comment: Thanks, mate, Your answer directed me to the right solution. The contact class was referring to System.Action rather than my class Action. That's why the compiler did not indicate that there is a problem until runtime. I could have looked a little deeper.

Comment: I recommend avoiding `Action` (and other common System types) for application-level code.. it can be fun times with imports. There is most usually a more precise name that can be given in the case of something like "action". Don't get me started about a nebulous `IDoAction` either ;-)